# How to disable "Cron Job" logging into system.log file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, cron, logging

My logs are being flooded with cron jobs updates. How can I disable this?

```
[2019-02-27 06:28:02] main.INFO: Cron Job outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup is run [] []
[2019-02-27 06:28:02] main.INFO: Cron Job outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00048398971557617,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1128,"realmem_start":138412032,"emalloc_start":136589928} [] []
[2019-02-27 06:28:03] main.INFO: Cron Job magento_newrelicreporting_cron is run [] []
[2019-02-27 06:28:03] main.INFO: Cron Job magento_newrelicreporting_cron is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0003509521484375,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":140509184,"emalloc_start":137617904} [] []
[2019-02-27 06:28:03] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is run [] []
[2019-02-27 06:28:03] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0062119960784912,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":551552,"realmem_start":134217728,"emalloc_start":121324440} [] []
[2019-02-27 06:28:03] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is run [] []
```

And so on ....

I found this in official docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

However, it doesn't say how to disable the logs...

I want to disable the logs for cron only. How can I achieve this? Is there a admin config or I have to do it manually?

Comment: In the end I've added a task to cron to delete the file. I do it less frequently than the Magento cron so I can see some output if I need to.

Comment: May I ask how you added that task to delete the cron.log? It's making me crazy. thanks!

Comment: Had same problem, wrote module that redirects cron log into separate file. [magento2-cronlogger](https://github.com/maxraddop/magento2-cronlogger)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, not enough of reputation.

You could also enable log rotation on that folder. If your server is running ubuntu or anything debian like just do the following:

```
# touch /etc/logrotate.d/magento2
```

with following contents

```
/var/www/website.com/httpdocs/var/log/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 14
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    su www-user www-data
    create 0664 www-user www-data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to make cron log file read only. Not a great solution but same as having a cron log cleaning process in place in my opinion.